# Why use a readonly modifier on a field that changes?

Tags: c#, modifier

In [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) tutorial by Josh Smith, a field is defined as readonly:

```
    public class CustomerRepository
    {

    readonly List<Customer> _customers;
    ...
    public CustomerRepository(string customerDataFile)
    {
        _customers = LoadCustomers(customerDataFile);
    }
    ...
    }
```

and later the readonly list, `_customers`, is updated:

```
    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("customer");

        if (!_customers.Contains(customer))
        {
            _customers.Add(customer);

            if (this.CustomerAdded != null)
                this.CustomerAdded(this, new CustomerAddedEventArgs(customer));
        }
    }
```

How this is allowed and what is the point of using readonly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `List<Customer>` variable itself (`_customers`) is `readonly` - that means you can't switch it out for an entirely different list, ensuring that everyone that's looking at it will always be seeing the same list.  You can, however, still change the elements *within* that list.

Comment: what if it was an object, would I be able to set new values to its properties?

Comment: @Saeid Yes - you're not modifying the value of the variable doing that, so you're not violating the `readonly` modifier.

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx):

> The `readonly` keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a field declaration includes a `readonly` modifier, **assignments to the fields** introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class

You cannot assign new value to `_customers` field, but you still change the elements within that list.

Answer (score 2):

`_customers.Add(customer);` does not update the list. This operator update the content of the list. If you want to update the list you must use something like `_customers= ...`. And this is prevented by the `readonly`

Answer (score 1):

The point of making the field readonly is that the reference cannot be changed. That means that you cannot write something like

```
_customers = null;
```

or

```
_customers = new List<Customer>();
```

Invoking the method .Add() accesses the collection through a method, and does not change the reference of the object.

This could be useful to prevent any NullReferenceException.